# Why does this hold for all continuous functions?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

For all $f$ continuous on $([0,1]^2,\mathcal{B}[0,1]^2,\lambda)$ then $f$ is Lebesgue integrable and 
$$\int_0^1\int_0^{x^2}f ~dy~dx=\int_0^1\int_{\sqrt{y}}^1f~dx~dy$$

Comment: Apply Fubini's theorem to $\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x,y) \mathbf{1}_{\{y \leqslant x^2\}} \, dy \, dx$.

Comment: Fubinis theorem holds for a product of functions'?

Comment: A continuous function $f$ is absolutely integrable. So too is the product of $f$ and the indicator function.

Comment: $[0, 1]^2$ is compact so $f$ is bounded and thus absolutely integrable on a bounded set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Fubini's theorem is applicable if the integrand is absolutely integrable on $[0,1]^2$.  It then follows that

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{x^2} f(x,y) \, dy \, dx= \int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x,y) \mathbf{1}_{\{y \leqslant x^2\}} \, dy \, dx
\\= \int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x,y) \mathbf{1}_{\{x \geqslant \sqrt{y}\}} \, dx \, dy
\\ = \int_0^1\int_{\sqrt{y}}^{1} f(x,y) \, dx \, dy$$

For integrability, note that $f$ is continuous and $|f(x,y) \mathbf{1}_{\{y \leqslant x^2\}} | \leqslant |f(x,y)|$.

Comment: Essentially now the answer with some details for you to fill in.

Comment: Thank you. The integrability of $f$ implies absolute integrability if I'm not mistaken right?

Comment: Yes.  A continuous function $f$ is Lebesgue (and Riemann) integrable on a bounded rectangle. Then it is easy to show that $|f|$ is integrable since $|f| = f^+ + f^-$ and the positive and negative parts are integrable.